# get hash ref key and value from another script

Tags: perl, hash, perl-module, ref

Hi all
I have a module with a sub that get its parameters from e.g. script.pl 
In script.pl I call the function this way moduleName::sunName(\%hashref).
Now in module, and in sub body I want to print those parameters that passed. also I want to check if the value of each key of this href is empty print '-' instead of 0.
first part of module:

```
sub printOptions {

   my $opt = shift;
   # I have this
   print $opt->{'id'};
   # But I need all parameters!
 }
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Matt, what are you getting at the moment? To dereference the reference $opt you can do

```
%opt = %{ $opt }
```

To iterate over the keys you can then do

```
for my $key ( sort keys %opt ) {
    print "$key: " . ($opt{ $key } || '-') . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Typo: you don't need `$value`.

Comment: Another one, you need round brackets not curly for the iterated list `(sort keys %opt)`

Comment: Thanks Joe. Last time I just type the comments here without testing. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sub printOptions {
  my $opt = shift @_;

  for my $key ( sort keys %$opt ){
    if( defined( $opt->{$key} )){
      print "$key: $opt->{$key}\n";
    }else{
      print "$key: undef\n";
    }
  }
}
```